# List of models in Model in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have two models:

```
class ModelIn{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

class ModelOut{
    public ModelOut(){ People = new List<ModelIn>();}
    public List<ModelIn> People { get; private set;}
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

And I have Controller editing ModelOut:

```
public ActionResult People()
{
    ...
    return View(SomeModelOutInstanceWith3People);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult(ModelOut items)
{
    ...
}
```

In view I have sth like:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%: Html.EditorFor(m => Model.Country) %>
    <% for(int i = 0; i < Model.People.Count; ++i){ %>
        <%: Html.EditorFor(m => Model.People[i].FirstName) %>
        <%: Html.EditorFor(m => Model.People[i].LastName) %>
        <%: Html.EditorFor(m => Model.People[i].Address) %>
    <% } %>
    <input type="submit" />
<% } %>
```

It works all OK, but in post action I have empty ModelOut items.
I can see in logs that data is sent correctly.

I have tried everything, nothing works.

Comment: Everything was working fine when I have had IList<ModelIn> instead of ModelOut

Comment: Try renaming it to `public ActionResult People(ModelOut model)` instead of just `m`. MVC can be picky about parameter names.

Comment: @David param name is items. I have this name when it was working with List<ModelIn> so I think problem must be elsewhere

Comment: What do you mean by "empty ModelOut m"? Is it null?

Comment: @petro.sidlovskyy No, default ModelOut is created. So items.Country is an empty string and items.People is an empty list.

Comment: @David You were right. MVC let me use items for model instance name when it is instance of `List<ModelIn>`, but doesn't let me use it for `ModelOut`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Dai were right. MVC let me use items for model instance name when it is instance of List, but doesn't let me use it for ModelOut.

After renaming `items` to `model` it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried simply `<%: Html.EditorFor(m => m.People) %>` ?

MVC should loop through the list by itself.

Also, watch out how you specify your lambdas, it should be `m => m` rather than `m => Model`.

*PS. I use MVC3...*

Comment: I need to loop through, because editors aren't only code I need there. In my code I have `m => m...`, I rewrote in with mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your problem could be a naming mismatch...from what I remember the default model binder does not do its job properly because of this naming mismatch....this means you need to specify more info to the model binder to do its job better... try updating your View code to use the below code for each property...

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(string.Format("People[{0}].FirstName", i), Model.People[i].FirstName) %>
```

The above view code will generate the following markup

```
<input id="People_0__FirstName" name="People[0].FirstName" type="text" />
```

I might have a syntactical problem above but I guess you can get it right with the help of  Visual Studio

Comment: It is exactly what my code generated. `<input class="text-box single-line" id="People_0__FirstName" name="People[0].FirstName" type="text" value="...">`

Comment: ok...now that we know that the mark up isn't wrong..can you post your complete View code as is...that is including the layout and model specifications? also I tried your scenario and it just worked fine...so there must be something outside that is preventing the model binder to bind data...